# Error: Cannot find module 'ieee754' - while running 'lb' command in Loopback js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to crete an application using loopback framework.
   I installed the application using the command

`npm install -g loopback-cli`

after then when i tried to create an application using 'lb' command an error threw.

[image: This is the screenshot of the loopback js]

need help ! and thanks in advance.

Comment: For me this problem ocurred when updating an existing loopback microservice. I just made a minimal change and the container broke. Why did loopback changed something? I cant find any reasons why this module is needed in working versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing globally via:  `npm install -g ieee754`

Answer (score 4):

Just manually install it. :)

npm i ieee754 --save-dev